# How to skip the first two lines in a file in c languange?

Tags: c, file

I am new to C programming and I am confused how to skip the first two lines in a file. I tried using `fgets` and `fscanf`, but I can't figured it out how to do it. Assume I have a file **txt** like this:

```
1 Username: Test
2 Password: 12345
3
4
```

So how can I start scan from line 3 and skip lines 1 and 2? Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] and show the code you have tried. `fgets` sounds good at first sight. Also show us the _actual_ file content (first 4-5 lines is enough)

Comment: How do you read the other lines? What about reading them in the same way and just throw the content away? There are lots of variants: Use `fgetc` in a loop until you get `'\n'`twice. Use `fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n]\n%*[^\n]\n");`. Use `fgets` twice.

Comment: Read *every* line with `fgets`. Don't mix it with `fscanf` use `sscanf` instead.

Comment: You have the concept "skip" in your head. Try to think about "discard".

Comment: @Gerhardh `fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n]\n%*[^\n]\n");` fails in various ways including is the first line is `"\n"` (nothing read) and it can read more than first 2 lines if the 2nd and 3rd are `"\n"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to skip a line from a standard stream:

- you can read a line with `fgets()` into a `char` array and ignore it. This will effectively consume the line if the array is long enough.
- you can use `fscanf()` with cryptic conversion specifications:

  ```
    fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n]");   // consume bytes different from newline, if any
    fscanf(fp, "%*1[\n]");   // consume a single newline, if present
  ```
- you can read and discard bytes with a simple loop:

  ```
    int c;
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;
  ```

To skip 2 lines, repeat the above code twice or better write a function `int skip_line(FILE *fp)` with the third option, returning `c` and call it twice.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// read and discard a line from stream fp, return EOF at end of file.
int skip_line(FILE *fp) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to skip two lines :

```
fscanf(fp,"%*[^\n]%*c%*[^\n]%*c");
```

Comment: This won't work of the first line is empty. You should use 4 different calls to `fscanf()` to account for potential empty lines.

Comment: Also will fail if the 2nd line is only `"\n"`.